# How to infer state of unknown variables given that you know something changed?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, logic, inference

There exists a game, whose state is quantified by `n` boolean variables `p_1`, `p_2`, ..., `p_n`. Assume `0 <= n <= 10`. The purpose of the game is to keep track of the state of as many variables as possible, and when they will change states (see below).

Only a subset of the variables may be observed at a time. We are always informed when the state of a variable changes from `true` to `false`, but only when the variable in question is being observed are we also informed which variable was changed.

If some `p_i` changes state from `true` to `false` at time `t`, then it will change state back from `false` to `true` at time `t + 60`.

Here are some example situations and the desired behavior. Assume that there are three variables, `p_1`, `p_2`, and `p_3`.

- All variables are observable. A variable changes state and by observation it is `p_1`. We know that `p_1` will change state back at `t + 60`.
- `p_1` and `p_2` are observable. A variable changes state. It should be inferred that it was `p_3`. We know that `p_3` will change state back at `t + 60`.
- `p_1` is observable, and it is known that `p_2` changed state to `false` at time `t - 30`. A variable changes state. It was not `p_1` by observation and `p_2` will only change state to `true` at `t + 30`, therefore it was `p_3`.
- No variables are observable It is known that `p_1` changed state to `false` at time `t - 30`, `p_2` changed state to `false` at `t - 75`, and `p_3` changed state to false at `t - 80`. A variable changes state. At `t + 1` `p_2` is observed to have a value of `true`. Because `p_1` is still `false`, and `p_2` has been observed to be `true`, it should be inferred that `p_3` is `false`, and will change state back to `true` at `t + 60`.
- `p_1` and `p_2` are observable. It is known that `p_3` changed state to `false` at time `t - 70`. No variable changes state. It should be inferred that `p_3` is true, since it would have changed from `false` to `true` at `t - 10`, and if it had changed from `true` to `false`, we would have been informed of a variable changing state.

One approach I have tried involved iterating over each of the variables on each notification of a variable state change, and ruling out the possible matches based on:

- whether it was visible and had not changed state
- whether its last state change is known and not far enough in the past for it to have changed back.

then, for the leftover variables for which state is known, determining an upper and lower bound on their last variable change based on when the variable was last observed in a particular state, when the variable may have changed state (back, from `false` to `true`), etc. Then if there exists only one variable change event within that bounds, it should be the one corresponding to the variable. It ended up being too cumbersome and I didn't continue. Every line was a burden because it seemed as if the number of possible combinations of states was too large and I would not take something into account.

Is the above approach a reasonable one to take, given the problem statement? Is there a general way that problems like this are modeled that allows them to be solved more elegantly?

Comment: I would suggest to model the process as a set of hypotheses. For each notification, create `n` hypotheses which variable has changed and combine them with the existing ones. Checking a hyptohesis' validity should be straight-forward (for each hypothesis, keep track of the intervals in which you know a variable's state). If you find an invalid one, just remove it. This might generate exponentially many valid hypotheses (but that's the result then). If you want only one solution, a depth first traversal through the hypothesis space might be a good idea (basically back tracking).

Comment: And maybe sort notifications by their time.

Comment: I think that could work. I'm imagining a tree where the nodes of level `i + 1` correspond to the possible states after `i` notifications. The edges are the hypotheses. The idea is that the notifications are processed "as they come in" and all that matters for scoring the current state, so only the lowest level would be needed, I think. On a new hypothesis or observation the contradictory leaves could be pruned and the successor states generated from the remainder. Isn't the worst case for number of possible states going to be `n^n`?

Comment: Yes, worst-case complexity is n_variables^n_notifications. But in the worst case, that's the number of valid solutions. So you can't get any better. Except if you want only one valid solution. Then, keeping track of all valid partial solutions is not necessary.

Comment: In my case I was interested in merging the states together to see what they all agree upon. I posted my solution as an answer inspired by your suggestions. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the advice of @NicoSchertler, I have come up with a solution which handles the uncertainty by creating sets of states based on a sequence of `Observations` and `Hypotheses`. An observation is a known state for a particular (observed) variable, whereas a hypothesis is notification of a state, but with no information concerning which variable it applies to. We are able to make the assumption that a hypothesis cannot apply to a variable which is under observation. This solution  does not handle the case where the start state is not known (yet).

There is a single starting state corresponding to the case where every variable is `true`. When provided a `hypothesis`, potentially multiple (`n`) successor states are generated by supposing that each unobserved variable is the subject of the `hypothesis`. Successor states that lead to contradiction are discarded. When provided an `observation`, a single successor state is generated for each current state. Any state that leads to contradiction is discarded. In this way the sequence of hypotheses and observations results in a set of possible states the variables may be in.

For my specific purpose, I wanted to know what could be known based on these states (as opposed to e.g. whether a valid solution exists). The states are combined and a result is returned that gives the state of each variable if that variable has the same state across all states.

Given `n` states and `m` notifications, the worst-case complexity is `n^m` which can be very limiting, but it should be fine for my limited application.

Here is the JavaScript implementation and test code.

**solver.js**

```
// Time for state to change back.
var STATE_CHANGE = 6e4;
// Possible notification lag.
var EPSILON = 2e3;

// Comparison operations.
function lt(a, b) {
  return a - b < EPSILON;
}

function gt(a, b) {
  return b - a < EPSILON;
}

function eq(a, b) {
  return Math.abs(a - b) < EPSILON;
}

// Object clone.
function clone(obj) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
}

module.exports = Solver;

/**
 * Solver solves boolean dynamic state.
 * @param {Array<string>} variables - array of variable names.
 */
function Solver(variables) {
  this.variables = {};
  this.states = [];
  this._time = null;
  var state = {};
  var time = Date.now();
  var self = this;
  // TODO: Handle unknown or variable start.
  variables.forEach(function (variable) {
    self.variables[variable] = {
      observed: false
    };
    state[variable] = {
      state: true,
      intervals: [{
        state: true,
        start: time,
        observed: false,
        end: null
      }]
    };
  });
  this.states.push(state);
}

// Set subset of variables as observed, the rest assumed not.
Solver.prototype.setObserved = function(variables) {
  var unobserved_variables = Object.keys(this.variables).filter(function (variable) {
    return variables.indexOf(variable) === -1;
  });
  var self = this;
  variables.forEach(function (variable) {
    self.variables[variable].observed = true;
  });
  unobserved_variables.forEach(function (variable) {
    self.variables[variable].observed = false;
  });
};

// Hypothesis has time, state.
Solver.prototype.addHypothesis = function(h) {
  this.updateVariables();
  var states = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < this.states.length; i++) {
    var newStates = this.applyHypothesis(this.states[i], h);
    if (newStates)
      Array.prototype.push.apply(states, newStates);
  }
  this.states = states;
};

// Observation has time, state, variable.
Solver.prototype.addObservation = function(o) {
  this.updateVariables();
  var states = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < this.states.length; i++) {
    var newState = this.applyObservation(this.states[i], o);
    if (newState)
      states.push(newState);
  }
  this.states = states;
};

// Get set of possible states.
Solver.prototype.getStates = function() {
  this.updateVariables();
  return this.states.slice();
};

// Get consolidated state.
// Each variable has state (true|false|null), change (if false). change
// is number or array (if there is disagreement)
Solver.prototype.getState = function() {
  this.updateVariables();
  // Construct output.
  var out = {};
  var state = this.states[0];
  for (var name in state) {
    var variable = state[name];
    if (variable.state) {
      out[name] = {
        state: variable.state
      };
    } else {
      var time = variable.intervals[variable.intervals.length - 1].end;
      out[name] = {
        state: variable.state,
        time: time
      };
    }
  }
  // Compare results across all states.
  return this.states.slice(1).reduce(function (out, state) {
    for (var name in out) {
      var out_variable = out[name],
          variable = state[name];
      // Check for matching states.
      if (out_variable.state === variable.state) {
        // Falsy check time.
        if (!out_variable.state) {
          // TODO: check undefined in case interval not updated?
          var change = variable.intervals[variable.intervals.length - 1].end;
          if (out_variable.time instanceof Array) {
            if (out_variable.time.indexOf(change) === -1) {
              out_variable.push(change);
            }
          } else if (out_variable.time !== change) {
            var times = [out_variable.time, change];
            out_variable.time = times;
          } // Else matches, so no problem.
        }
      } else {
        // Conflicted states.
        out_variable.state = null;
        // In case it was set.
        delete out_variable.time;
      }
    }
    return out;
  }, out);
};

// Update `false` state variables based on false end
// time, if present.
Solver.prototype.updateVariables = function() {
  var time = this._time || Date.now();
  for (var i = 0; i < this.states.length; i++) {
    var state = this.states[i];
    for (var name in state) {
      var variable = state[name];
      // Update changeback.
      if (!variable.state) {
        if (variable.intervals.length > 0) {
          var last = variable.intervals[variable.intervals.length - 1];
          if (last.end && last.end <= time) {
            // update to true.
            variable.state = true;
            variable.intervals.push({
              state: true,
              start: time,
              end: null
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

// Return state with observation applied or null if invalid.
Solver.prototype.applyObservation = function(state, observation) {
  var variable = state[observation.variable];
  if (variable.state && !observation.state) {
    // Change in observed variable true -> false
    variable.state = observation.state;
    variable.intervals.push({
      state: variable.state,
      start: observation.time,
      end: observation.time + STATE_CHANGE
    });
    return state;
  } else if (variable.state && observation.state) {
    // Expected state.
    return state;
  } else if (!variable.state && observation.state) {
    // Potentially updating variable.
    var time = variable.intervals[variable.intervals.length - 1];
    if (eq(time, observation.time)) {
      // update state.
      variable.state = observation.state;
      variable.intervals.push({
        state: observation.state,
        start: observation.time,
        end: null
      });
      return state;
    } else {
      // Could not update this variable.
      return null;
    }
  } else if (!variable.state && !observation.state) {
    // Expected state.
    return state;
  }
};

// Returns multiple states or null if invalid
Solver.prototype.applyHypothesis = function(state, hypothesis) {
  hypothesis = clone(hypothesis);
  var states = [];
  for (var name in state) {
    // Skip observed variables, no guessing with them.
    if (this.variables[name].observed)
      continue;
    var newState = clone(state);
    var variable = newState[name];
    // Hypothesis is always false.
    if (variable.state) {
      // Change in observed variable true -> false
      variable.state = hypothesis.state;
      variable.intervals.push({
        state: variable.state,
        start: hypothesis.time,
        end: hypothesis.time + STATE_CHANGE
      });
    } else {
      newState = null;
    }
    if (newState !== null) {
      states.push(newState);
    }
  }
  if (states.length === 0) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return states;
  }
};
```

**test-solver.js**

```
var Solver = require('./solver');

var p_1 = "p_1",
    p_2 = "p_2",
    p_3 = "p_3";
var solver = new Solver([p_1, p_2, p_3]);

var t = Date.now();

solver.setObserved([p_1, p_2, p_3]);
solver._time = t + 5e3;
solver.addObservation({
  variable: p_1,
  state: false,
  time: t + 5e3
});

var result = solver.getState();
if (!result[p_1].state && result[p_1].time === t + 65e3 &&
    result[p_2].state &&
    result[p_3].state) {
  console.log("PASS: Test 1.");
} else {
  console.log("FAIL: Test 1.");
}

solver = new Solver([p_1, p_2, p_3]);
solver.setObserved([p_1, p_2]);
solver._time = t + 5e3;
solver.addHypothesis({
  state: false,
  time: t + 5e3
});

result = solver.getState();
if (result[p_1].state &&
    result[p_2].state &&
    !result[p_3].state && result[p_3].time === t + 65e3) {
  console.log("PASS: Test 2.");
} else {
  console.log("FAIL: Test 2.");
}

solver = new Solver([p_1, p_2, p_3]);
solver.setObserved([p_1]);
solver._time = t - 30e3;
solver.addObservation({
  variable: p_2,
  time: t - 30e3,
  state: false
});
solver._time = t;
solver.addHypothesis({
  state: false,
  time: t
});

var result = solver.getState();
if (result[p_1].state &&
    !result[p_2].state && result[p_2].time === t + 30e3 &&
    !result[p_3].state && result[p_3].time === t + 60e3) {
  console.log("PASS: Test 3.");
} else {
  console.log("FAIL: Test 3.");
}

solver = new Solver([p_1, p_2, p_3]);
solver._time = t - 80e3;
solver.addObservation({
  variable: p_3,
  time: t - 80e3,
  state: false
});
solver._time = t - 75e3;
solver.addObservation({
  variable: p_2,
  time: t - 75e3,
  state: false
});
solver._time = t - 30e3;
solver.addObservation({
  variable: p_1,
  time: t - 30e3,
  state: false
});
solver._time = t;
solver.addHypothesis({
  state: false,
  time: t
});
result = solver.getState();
if (!result[p_1].state && result[p_1].time === t + 30e3 &&
    result[p_2].state === null &&
    result[p_3].state === null) {
  console.log("PASS: Test 4.");
} else {
  console.log("FAIL: Test 4.");
}
solver._time = t + 1;
solver.addObservation({
  variable: p_2,
  time: t + 1,
  state: true
});
var result = solver.getState();
if (!result[p_1].state && result[p_1].time === t + 30e3 &&
    result[p_2].state &&
    !result[p_3].state && result[p_3].time === t + 60e3) {
  console.log("PASS: Test 5.");
} else {
  console.log("FAIL: Test 5.");
}
```